# I get the following error when i try to connect sonarqube with azure devops build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

> [error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was:
>   { "code": "ECONNREFUSED", "errno": "ECONNREFUSED",
>     "syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":9000 }

I have configured sonarqube and it's running fine on localhost.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Try to add more relevant information to your question. Why do you think Azure DevOps can reach SonarQube; do you still use localhost somewhere?

Comment: Hi @B. Akshay Did you get a chance to try out below answer? Please let me know how did it go? We can discuss it to work out a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to run your build pipeline on your on-premise agent in order to integrate with your local sonarque server. For cloud hosted agent cannot access local your SQ server with address 127.0.0.1:9000.

It is easy to install and configure self-hosted agents, please check the microsoft official detailed guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops).

Please check the **exercise 2** [here](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/sonarqube/#exercise-2-modify-the-build-to-integrate-with-sonarqube) for detailed steps to integrate build pipeline with SonarQube .

However you can also follow the detailed steps in **exercise 1** [here](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/sonarqube/) to create a sonarque server hosted on azure. Azure hosted SQ server works with both on-premise agents and microsoft-hosted agents.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure SonarQube to your localhost - but only save the config - don´t test.
To use SQ in your case it is needed that you have installed a Self Hosted Agent on your machine, because this agent would be able to access SQ@Localhost => Means in Build you can use your